# Creating Products with Stripe API in Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, e-commerce

Creating my first proper website and trying to connect Stripe for payments. Their API doesnt seem very dynamic(im probably reading wrong tho). Trying to integrate their [checkout page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout).

Im confused on how to make multiple products at once. Tried to loop through my OrderItems:

```
def checkout(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    order = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    for item in items:
        stripe.Product.create(
            name = item.name
            description= item.desc
        )
        stripe.Price.create(
            product= product.id,
            unit_amount=int(order.get_cart_total),
            currency='gbp',
        )
```

But was stuck on how to declare the product ID for Price.create

Was also confused on this part of their API:

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  payment_method_types=['card'],
  line_items=[{
    'price': '{{PRICE_ID}}',
    'quantity': 1,
  }],
  mode='payment',
  success_url='https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
  cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',
```

Ive not hosted my site on anything yet so what can I set the URLs to? and where does Checkout_session come from? Cant find any info thats up to date on this so I apologise for asking whats probably not a great question but not sure what to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Stripe, every API request returns a JSON response that can then be deserialized in the corresponding API resource. This means that when you call the Create Product [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create) you get a `Product` back and when you call the Create Price [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) your get a `Price` back.

Most API resources that you interact with will have an id. So for a `Product` it's `prod_123456` and for a `Price` it's `price_abcdefg`.

In your code, you need to store the result of the Product creation in a variable so that you can reference it when creating the Price.

```
def checkout(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    order = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    for item in items:
        product = stripe.Product.create(
            name = item.name
            description= item.desc
        )
        price = stripe.Price.create(
            product= product.id,
            unit_amount=int(order.get_cart_total),
            currency='gbp',
        )
```

Similarly, when you go and try to create the Session, you need to make sure you set the list of line items to have the right price id(s) that you just created.

Similarly, in most cases, you would already have created your product and price catalog in Stripe ahead of time. The idea is that you already know which products you are selling and at which price points and you set all of this up in Stripe. Later, your own order model will reference those Price and Product ids when you go and create a Checkout Session.

If you only want one-off products, then what you should do instead is create them inline when you create the Checkout Session by using `price_data` as a [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data).

Finally, for the URL part, this would be the URL of your website where you want to send the customer back to after paying. The idea is that after going to pay on your website you redirect your customer to Checkout directly on Stripe. Once they paid, Stripe will send them back to you, to a specific URL you provided in that call so that you can thank them for the order. This is covered in the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#payment-success). Similarly the `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` part in the URL is just a magic value that Stripe will replace with the real Checkout Session id `cs_test_1234567` when they send the customer back to your website.

*(You likely want to talk to [Stripe's support team](https://support.stripe.com/contact) directly if you have follow-up questions though)*